# When `sync` is enabled, hiding/showing dataset is also sync'ed?

Tags: javascript, plugins, charts, chart.js

## Situation

I have multiple charts in my page that show different datasets.

I want to use `chartjs-plugin-crosshair` to be able to show vertical lines on hover.

I also want to sync the vertical lines so that I can the vertical on the same date.

## Bug

Both of the above work, except I noticed a weird bug where enabling `sync: {enabled: true}` means hiding/showing a dataset of one chart hides/shows a dataset of another (even though they have different keys)

When I make `sync: {enabled: false}`, the weird bug stops, but then I lose the feature of syncing the vertical lines.

I looked through the code of the plugin but I don't see anything that changes the `hidden` property of datasets.

## Plugin config

The plugin config is simple:

```
    crosshair: {
      ...
      sync: {
        enabled: true, // enable trace line syncing with other charts
        group, // chart group
        suppressTooltips: false, // suppress tooltips when showing a synced tracer
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
```

[image: Bug image]

For confidentiality reasons I had to hide some info with red boxes. When I toggle a label on the first chart (top left) some of the labels of the others ones also get toggled. I never touch any of the labels of the remaining charts.

What gives?